# Display brightness not show in keyboard shortcuts. Help me pls!

Tags: macos, keyboard, display, shortcut

[image]

> Blockquote

i can't see display in image. i am boring, if you have ideal, help me pls.

Comment: Did you check the list of keyboard shortcuts? Those are mission control...

Comment: i check again and i don't see it.

Comment: Such shortcuts are bound to the F keys I think. If you want to adjust brightness. Go to display settings. Further, if you search "display" or "brightness" in the top right search bar, you will find all the relevant places to look for it. (ping me by @ankii)

Comment: i try it but i don't see it... i think i need reinstall system -_-

Comment: What computer and keyboard are you using?

Comment: i use macbook pro 13inch nontouchbar 2017 and keyboard is niz 84 bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to change the keyboard shortcut for display brightness to a different shortcut than the dedicated display brightness key on an Apple keyboard, or else you want to set a custom keyboard shortcut on a non-Apple keyboard for display brightness. That is not possible with the System Preferences in current versions of macOS.

You may use a keyboard re-mapping application such as the free [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html). After installing it, open the application and select the "Simple Modifications" tab or the "Function keys" tab if you want to remap the function keys. Choose the key you want to use, then from the right drop-down menu, choose "display_brightness_decrement" (or increment) under the "Media controls" section.

Additional information is available in the [documentation](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html).

Alternatively you can use the commercial application [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/), or other simialr keyboard-rempapping applications.